# Number of zeros elementary functions

Tags: functions, derivatives, logarithms, roots

While studying functions and zeros of functions i came across the following problem:

**Problem:**

Knowing that $1,09<\ln 3<1,1,$ determine ***the number of zeros*** of $J: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $J(x)=3^{x}-1-2 x^{2}$

**Attempt:**

One quickly notices that $x = 0$ satisfies the expression given in the problem. Now, one can draw the functions $3^{x}$ and $2x^2 + 1$ and notice that for $x < 0$ is not possible  that $3^x = 1 + 2x^2$

Therefore, we should investigate what happens when $x > 0$. For that, i tried solving $$
g^{\prime}(x)>h^{\prime}(x)
$$

where $g(x) = 3^x$ and $h(x) = 1 + 2x^2$. The ideia behind solving the above inequality comes from the fact that if $g^{\prime}(x)>h^{\prime}(x)$ for every $x > 0$, then it would not possible for $g(x) = h(x)$ for $x > 0$ (Just intuition, i dont know if that holds in general)

However, $$
g^{\prime}(x)>h^{\prime}(x) \Rightarrow \ln (3) \cdot 3^{x}>4 x+1
$$

It looks like we are on the right track, since the term $\ln(3)$ just appeared. Now, by observing that $$
1,1 \cdot 3^{x}> ln(3) \cdot 3^x> 4 x+1>4 x
$$

we see that $$
\frac{1,1 \cdot 3^{x}}{x}>4
$$ which i dont know how to solve.

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: +1 to your query, for very good work shown.  As a minor constructive criticism, if you have a query, where Calculus methods are *not out of bounds*, and you personally have a reasonably working knowledge of Calculus (as evidenced by the work that you've shown), then it is not a good idea to tag the query "algebra-precalculus".  That tag indicates to reviewers that Calculus methods are *out-of-bounds*.

Comment: In the present query, the fact that you also tagged the query "derivatives" is a good signal, that maybe *some* Calculus methods are okay.

Comment: @user2661923 I agree with you! In fact, i just deleted the "algebra-precalculus" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it is easy to verify that $x = 0, 1, 2$ are all zeros of $J$.

We can show that these are the only zeros of $J$, in the following order:

1. Show that $J''$ is strictly increasing, and deduce that $J''$ has exactly one zero, which lies in the interval $(0, 2)$. We call this zero $z$.
2. Show that $J'$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $(-\infty, z)$ and strictly increasing on the interval $(z, \infty)$. Deduce that $J'$ has exactly two zeros, which lie in the intervals $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$, respectively. We call them $z_1$ and $z_2$.
3. Show that $J$ is strictly increasing on the intervals $(-\infty, z_1)$ and $(z_2, \infty)$ and is strictly decreasing on the interval $(z_1, z_2)$. Thus $J$ has at most three zeros, which we have all found.

Comment: It looks good! I am going to write down each step to see if i can understand it. However, what did you think of my approach? Can the problem be solved by using/extending the original attempt?

Comment: This is in some sense an extension to your approach. In order to determine when $g'(x) > h'(x)$ (i.e. when $J'(x) > 0$), we make use of $J''$.

Comment: Regarding step 1: How can you determine that $J^{\prime \prime}$ has exactly one zero in $(0, 2)$? I can see that there is at least one zero in the aforementioned interval, but i just cant see why there is exactly one

Comment: Because it is strictly increasing. A strictly increasing function cannot have two zeros.

Comment: Regarding step 2: How did you deduce that $J^{\prime}$ has exactly two zeros, which lie in the intervals $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$? I found that this involved solving $3^{x}\log(3) = 4x$, which i dont know how to solve.

Comment: To show that $J'$ has at most two zeros, you use the same argument as above. To show that $J'$ has two zeros in the corresponding intervals, use [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).

Comment: How did you deduce that $J$ satisfies the properties in step 3? I thought that step 2 would imply those properties, but i just cant see it

Comment: More specifically, how can i show that $J$ is increasing in $(z_{2}, \infty)$?

Comment: Can you further elaborate the answer? I am finding hard to put together some pieces

Comment: $J'$ is strictly positive on $(z_2,\infty)$ and hence $J$ is increasing on that interval.

Comment: How do you show that $J^{\prime}$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $(-\infty, z)$ and strictly increasing on the interval $(z, \infty)$?

Comment: Because $J''$ is negative/positive on the respective intervals.